# Python classes to Yaml/JSON

Tags: python, json, inheritance, yaml, salt-stack

I am not happy with YAML/JSON.

I am missing inheritance.

Is it possible to export a hierarchy of Python classes to YAML/JSON?

This way I can use my favorite IDE with auto-completion to build my data structures.

The result should be fed into SaltStack in my case. But this is not related to configuration management at all, since the result should be plain YAML/JSON.

I want to export the classes to yaml. There will always be classes only, never instances. At least that's what I think today.

I think it makes sense to use this constraint: classes won't have methods, except properties. And only get-properties, never set-properties.

I took the example json from: https://www.json2yaml.com/

```
{
  "json": [
    "rigid",
    "better for data interchange"
  ],
  "yaml": [
    "slim and flexible",
    "better for configuration"
  ],
  "object": {
    "key": "value",
    "array": [
      {
        "null_value": null
      },
      {
        "boolean": true
      },
      {
        "integer": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "paragraph": "Blank lines denote\nparagraph breaks\n",
  "content": "Or we\ncan auto\nconvert line breaks\nto save space"
}
```

Here is one example of above json in python syntax:

```
class json:
    data = ['rigi', 'better for data interchange']


class yaml:
    data = ['slim and flexible', 'better for configuration']


class object:
    key = 'value'
    array = [dict(null_value=None), dict(boolean=True), dict(integer=1)]


class paragraph:
    data = 'Blank lines denote\nparagraph breaks\n'


class content:
    data = '''Or we
can auto
convert line breaks
to save space'''
```

Above is just a simple of how data structures could get created using python classes.

Comment: YAML has inheritance.

Comment: Do you want to export the *class definitions* into YAML or the *class instances*?

Comment: @flyx I updated the question: "I want to export the classes to yaml. There will always be classes only, never instances. At least that's what I think today."

Comment: Well, the question is then what you want to export. Only the hierarchy or also information about the classes' methods?

Comment: @flyx I updated the question: "I think it makes sense to use this constraint: classes won't have methods, except properties. And only get-properties, never set-properties." With other word: the hierarchy and the data of the classes.

Comment: I think you should show some input Python code so that we see exactly what you are working with. I am not sure what you refer to with *property* in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/). Note the security caveats of using pickle also applies to jsonpickle. If you want to allow de/serializing arbitrary objects, you necessarily have to deal with the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json.Encoder`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) , extend it to write custom class to parse Python classes something like below..

Since you can have different types of objects custom encoder is recommended.

For ex .

```
json.dumps(str)
# TypeError: Object of type 'mappingproxy' is not JSON serializable
```

I am not sure if you are looking for `jsonpickle`

```
jsonpickle.dumps(str)
>>'{"py/type": "__builtin__.str"}'

jsonpickle.dumps(json.dumps)
>>'{"py/function": "json.dumps"}'
```

and

```
import json
class ClassEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, type1):
            return obj.conversion
        # .type2
        # .
        # .type3
        # .
        # .so on
        # .
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

dict_str = json.dumps(class_object, cls=ClassEncoder)
```

From dict_str dump it to YAML too.

```
yaml.dump(dict_str)
```